# Shiny App: How to collect all text inputs into a data frame without listing them individually (how to index reactive values?)

Tags: r, shiny

I have a tab of my app where I display a bunch of text inputs based on a three-column data frame that contains: variable_name, text_prompt, and example_data. The code below seems to work fine since it displays how I want it to. Eventually, I will be feeding it different data frames, depending on the circumstances, so I need to be able to do everything programmatically.

```
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)
library(DT)

additional.data.fields <- tibble (var.name = c("project.id", "director.name"), 
                                  prompt.text = c("Enter Project ID", "Enter Director's name"),
                                  var.value = c("e.g. 09-111", "e.g. Paul Smith"))

ui <- fluidPage(
    tabsetPanel(
        #Generate Input fields from dataframe
        tabPanel("Input", #value = "input.2",
                 # Generate input fields with pmap
                 actionButton("submit", "Submit"),
                 pmap(additional.data.fields, ~textInput(..1, ..2, value = ..3)),
        ),
        #Output data to tell if it updates with button click
        tabPanel("Output", value = "output",
                 DT::dataTableOutput("data")
        )
    )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
    # Create a reactive values object to store the input data
    values <- reactiveValues()
    
    # Set the reactive values object when the submit button is clicked
    observeEvent(input$submit, {
        var.names <- pull(additional.data.fields, var.name)
        #THIS IS THE PART I DON'T KNOW HOW TO DO
        #input.data <- ???
        #I'll add dummy data so that the program loads
        input.data <- tibble(var.names, 
                            temp = 1:length(var.names))
        values$data <- input.data
    })
    
    # Render the input data table
    output$data <- DT::renderDataTable({
        values$data
    })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

But what I want - and really have no idea how to do - is to get it back into a data frame after the user hits "submit" (I only need two columns in the subsequent data frame; I don't need the text_prompt data again.)

I know that the user input creates a list of read-only ReactiveValues called "input". But I can't figure out how to do anything with this list besides access using known names (i.e. I know that there is a variable named "project_id" which I can access using input$project_id). But what I want is not to have to write them all out, so that I can change the data used to create the input fields. So I need a way to collect them in a data frame without knowing all the individual names of the variables or even how many there are.

Comment: Hello, you have more chance to get help if you provide a working code and sample data rather than a sample of code.

Comment: Thanks @HubertL. I've updated my question. I also managed to solve it (see answer below) but would be interested if you have any insights into why [[]] works whereas [] does not. Regardless, thanks for taking a look at my question!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out on my own. You can't index reactive values with []. However, for some reason you can using [[]].

I would love to know why this is, if anyone has an answer that can help me understand why it works this way.

Here's the key bit of code that I was missing before:

```
input.data <- tibble (names = var.names,
                      values = map_chr(var.names, ~input[[.x]]))
```

The full code that works as I want it is pasted below. I'd still appreciate any feedback or recommendations for improvement.

```
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)
library(DT)

additional.data.fields <- tibble (var.name = c("project.id", "director.name"), 
                                  prompt.text = c("Enter Project ID", "Enter Director's name"),
                                  var.value = c("e.g. 09-111", "e.g. Paul Smith"))

ui <- fluidPage(
    tabsetPanel(
        #Generate Input fields from dataframe
        tabPanel("Input", #value = "input.2",
                 # Generate input fields with pmap
                 actionButton("submit", "Submit"),
                 pmap(additional.data.fields, ~textInput(..1, ..2, value = ..3)),
        ),
        #Output data to tell if it updates with button click
        tabPanel("Output", value = "output",
                 DT::dataTableOutput("data")
        )
    )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
    # Create a reactive values object to store the input data
    values <- reactiveValues()
    
    # Set the reactive values object when the submit button is clicked
    observeEvent(input$submit, {
        var.names <- pull(additional.data.fields, var.name)
        input.data <- tibble (names = var.names,
                              values = map_chr(var.names, ~input[[.x]]))
        values$data <- input.data
    })
    
    # Render the input data table
    output$data <- DT::renderDataTable({
        values$data
    })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```